# Javascript - Trying to use Array.lenght to access last element of each array in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I need to display preview of user text messages from an array. I achieve this easily if I hardcode the number in the loop. It works but it's not pretty. A prettier solution would be to display last text message received or sent. My attempt at doing this with `Array.Length` is failing miserably because not all users have the same number of text messages. If a user has 4 messages and another 2 messages, then it will cause an undefined error when looping over the users with less messages. How can this be done?

```
txt.details[0].message //works but not pretty
```

function

```
function getSMS(){
usersms.forEach(function (txt,counter) {
//
//
//get total number of msgs per user
var usertxtarray = txt.details;
var length = (usertxtarray).length;
console.log('msgs per user : ' + length);//prints 2, 2, 4

//display sms preview
var sms = (txt.details[length].message).substring(0,35) + '...';

//etc... 

});
}
```

Here's what `(txt.details)` looks like

```
[
  {
    "direction": "from",
    "user": {
      "id": "23",
      "avatar": "myavatar.jpg",
      "first_name": "Jane",
      "last_name": "Doe",
    },
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "smsid": "2220",
    "date": "202-12-29",
    "time": "12:00",
    "timezone": "Eastern Standard Time"
  },
  {
    "direction": "to",
    "user": {
      "id": "23",
      "avatar": "myavatar.jpg",
      "first_name": "Jane",
      "last_name": "Doe",
    },
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor  sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "smsid": "2220",
    "date": "2021-01-05",
    "time": "09:00",
    "timezone": "Eastern Standard Time"
  }
]
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are zero-indexed.

So if your length = 4, then your last item is at index 3.

So ...

```
var sms = txt.details[length - 1].message.substring(0, 35) + '...';
```

will give you the last message.